# axios network error with cors activated still returns error

Tags: node.js, axios

the link to the code [link](http://github.com/charbelsako/devnetwork)

I am using axios and nodejs.
All routes work and give a response except one. which returns `Network error`.
that route is /api/ads/myads.

The route works on its own but when used with redux actions it doesn't

The network tab says that this request was blocked.
So I tried to add cors but that didn't solve the issue.

The file in question is .../actions/adActions this one is producing the error while others don't

I will be uploading the code in a minute

Comment: uploaded the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be my adblocker thinking this was actual ads